# How to show if a world line is null for a particular metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

For the Kerr metric, with line element
$$
ds^2 = -\frac{\Delta-a^2\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}dt^2 - \frac{4Mar\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}dtd\phi +\frac{(r^2+a^2)^2-a^2\Delta\sin^2\theta}{\rho^2}\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 +\frac{\rho^2}{\Delta}dr^2+\rho^2d\theta^2
$$
in the Boyer-Linquist coordinates
$$
\Delta = r^2 - 2Mr +a^2\\
\rho^2 = r^2 + a^2\cos^2\theta
$$
where $M$ and $a$ are constants and rotation axis is $\theta =0$. How can I show that the world-line
$$
\vec{R} = (t, r_+,\theta_0,\phi_0+\Omega t)
$$
is null for
$$
\Omega\equiv\Omega_+ = \frac{a}{r^2_++a^2}
$$
? Note that $r_+$ and $r_-$ are the solutions for $\Delta = 0$.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Past exam question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your metric is wrong. The $dtd{\phi}$ component in particular. I just tried it with the metric from my notes and it's quite simple. Just find $\frac{d\vec{R}}{d\lambda}$ and use the metric to find its magnitude

Comment: I just checked again and I don't think I've copied it down wrong.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. In the form I have it's written with a delta in it, but simplifies to what you have once subbing in delta. So where are you getting stuck? Have you worked out $\frac{d\vec{R}}{d\lambda}$ and subbed it in? Remember that since the worldline has $r=r_+$ you can sub that in to the metric (and so get rid of all deltas).

Comment: Yea I've solved it but too lazy to write my own solution. It didn't occur to me that deltas would be zero. I did it by direct substitution without doing $\frac{d\vec{R}}{d\lambda}$(How would u do that?).Anyway I'll just accept your answer. You can edit to add stuff in if u want.

Comment: Thanks, laziness is the same reason I didn't type out my solution on here. That and I think it's frowned upon here to write out solutions to homework style questions (even though this is a past paper).

Comment: We don't get solutions for our past papers. So we wouldn't know if we've calculated something right or wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you asked how you would do $\frac{d\vec{R}}{d\lambda}$. You just take the derivative of each component. To finish the question you don't need to know the explicit form of $\frac{d\vec{R}}{d\lambda}$. Just that $\frac{d\vec{R}}{d\lambda}=(\frac{dt}{d\lambda},0,0,\Omega \frac{dt}{d\lambda})$  then you sub it in as is. What did you substitute in? Just $\vec{R}$?

Comment: Yea I just subbed in $\vec{R}$ and made $\Delta = 0$. Rearranging it finds that $dR^2 = \Delta(r=r_+)dt^2$ which is 0.